# RIP Tina Turner

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Rock and Roll/Rhythm and Blues icon [Tina Turner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tina_Turner) passed away at her home in Switzerland today, at age 83.

Although most knew the "Queen of Rock'n'Roll" for her music career, Science Fiction fans remember Tina for her role as the ruthless [Auntie Entity](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Aunty_Entity) in the 1985 blockbuster *[Mad Max: Beyond Thunderdome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Max_Beyond_Thunderdome)* and the hit song "[We Don't Need Another Hero](https://youtu.be/Gcm-tOGiva0)" she recorded for that movie.

Comment: Her acting chops were on display.  Auntie was memorable. 